# 2D Array Filling at a specific point

Tags: c#

For this program i've asked the user to input the array size then its filled with numbers in chronological order until the array is full. I Want to then put this array into the grid. I was wondering if it's possible to start the input of the array at a certain point, say its was the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 10. Would i be able to start the input at a certain point like [0,2], so basically not use the first slots to make the grid like;

```
[] [] [1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6] [7] [8]
[9] [10] [] [] []
```

i was wondering if and how i would be able to do this
Thank you in advance!

```
    class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

        int Height = 4;
        int Width = 5;

        int[,] grid = new int[Height, Width];

        Console.Write("Input Number: ");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] InputNumber = new int[number];
        var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, number).ToArray();

        /*
        [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [0,4]
        [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [1,4] 
        [2,0] [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4] 
        [3,0] [3,1] [3,2] [3,3] [3,4]*/

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need a nested for loop to add your integers to your grid array.  Once you have that, all you need to do is offset where you start the array or add a skip count.  Once you have more code written, it will become clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may modify your code to include the cells offset, as following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Height = 4;
        int Width = 5;
        int[,] grid = new int[Height, Width];
        Console.Write("Start Number :");
        int startnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("End Number :");
        int endnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("input nmber of cells to be offset at max "+Width*Height+" :");
        int cellofs = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var myNumbers = Enumerable.Range(startnum, endnum).ToArray();
        int t = 1;
        for(int i=cellofs;i<Width*Height;i++)
        {
            int iline = i / Width;
            int jcol = i % Width;
            if (t <= (endnum - startnum))
            {
                grid[iline, jcol] = myNumbers[t];
                t++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(grid[i, j]+" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Hope these help.

Comment: That code would leave all the columns on the left empty. In the question, only cells before the starting position are affected.

Comment: The line `int[] InputNumber = new int[number];` is useless. There is no need to allocate any memory as `Enumerable.Range` already create an array.

Comment: Also, it does not make much sense to create a range from `1` to `number` and increment `t` from `0` to `number - 1`. You could initialize `t` with `1` and remove the array `InputNumber` in that case or use the enumerator directly if you want the code to be a more generic.

Comment: Considering that the question refers to first cells to be left empty, I made some modifications in the quoted code, hope they fullfill the needs of the question.